# Trying to upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 15.10, not working due to "broken packages"

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, updates, 15.10

I am writing this while I am really tired, so please, bear with me while trying to explain my troubles here :) 
I am trying to update to 15.10 from 14.04 LTS. 
I have done some basic troubleshooting by searching all over on google for hours. So what have I done? 
 1. I have done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` at least 10 - 15 times 
 2. I have gone in to the directory `/var/log/dist-upgrade` and checked in the `apt.log` in there after broken packages... let's just say that the list contains 50+ packages, where as I noticed some strange thing about them. Most of them are listed as "broken" in there because a 64-bit version depends on a 32-bit version of the same program. which I went through at least 25 of those cases (just looking, not doing anything), and after that I saw the pattern. Most cases, if not all cases (doubt it) were like that. 
 3. I have unmarked all the PPA's I've added by myself, and then removed all of the nvidia drivers (a fan on my graphics card broke and started to vibrate my MBoard to bits), I thought that maybe those would help, but sadly it did not. 
While deleting programs I thought I should do some `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get purge` to see if what would be taken away, and that was about 50+ packages (I think).
now, I got a decent amount of paste to stick here, so I went over to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/H4Reg5qe) and glued it stuck there instead

Still nothing works, so here I am asking this community for help, and hopefully we can get this riddle solved :)

Cheers

/ F4rm0r

Edit:
As it turns out 16.04 is just around the corner, and as I had forgotten completely to look it up (due to being tired) I have now decided that I will wait approximately 4 weeks for it to be properly released.
Thank you for all of your suggestions so far, appreciated!  :)

Comment: You might want to see what a `sudo apt-get install -f` does.

Comment: Not a solution, but it's not standard to go from a LTS to a 6 month release, especially when you're missing the cumulative 6 month releases.  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment section, you need to run the following command and then post the errors if any:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It should be noted that this is a real gutsy way to upgrade to a new version. I can't say that I don't do it myself as it does come with advantages but broken package management if at least temporary should be expected. If the above command doesn't work, post the errors and we will go from there.

It should also be noted that this may not be so easy as there is a transition to systemd that apt-get may not fully be able to handle.

Normally, you should run the following command to do the upgrade:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

In a few weeks, 16.04 will be released and then you would run the following instead:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You may have to wait until then as this is the next LTS release and so an upgrade from 14.04 should be expected.

As always, possibly consider some sleep as things may seem more easy in the morning.

Comment: Oh, it's only a few weeks left? I did not knew that, I thought it were a matter of months left, like it would be released in end of April or may somewhere there... I have to look it up and then I can come with an answer about if I am going to upgrade or not. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: Yeah, I looked it up and I think I can wait approx a month for the next LTS release, thank you for enlightening me about it, as I had forgotten how convenient the release numbers are (16.04 for example stands for 2016 April, if I am not incorrect) cheers!